# C# readonly access to List<> or other collection, or ToArray() magic

Tags: c#, collections, generic-collections

1st question is about way of protecting my List from changing(remove/add/clear etc...) from outside

there is my way:

```
class Foo 
{
    public int[] MyCollection
    {
        get{ return (_myCollection==null)?null:_myCollection.ToArray();
    }
    protected List<int> _myCollection;
}
```

Is it good? Or is there any better ideas, or may be patterns?

2nd:
When iam testing this solution with stopwatch, i was very surprised.

List -enumeration was slower than List.ToArray() enumeration with cast time:

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>();
for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
{
    myList.Add(j);
}
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    //casting every iteration:
    var ROC = myList.ToArray();
    int count = 0;
    foreach (var a in ROC)
    {
        count += a;
    }
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
```

It shows me 700 msec, and

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>();
for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
{
    myList.Add(j);
}
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    int count = 0;
    //No casting at all
    foreach (var a in myList)
    {
        count += a;
    }
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
```

Shows me 843 msec... why is it so?

Comment: If you have two separate questions then ask two separate questions; don't include two different questions (that aren't closely related, and these aren't) in one question.

Comment: Concerning the stopwatch timing aspect: Looking at the IL code in ILSpy (or an equivalent tool) is usually good for these types of questions.

Comment: Did you time a release build from outside the debugger?

Comment: it is not separated 4 me, cause if it is realy fast - then there is no reasons to use any other accessToList.

Comment: @Matthew Watson  mmm whats means "time a release build from outside the debugger", i'am never heard about it

Comment: He means just that. **Never try to do performance timing with the debugger running**. The customer won't be running the debugger, and running the debugger **massively** changes the performance characteristics of a program. I am in the middle of a series on tech.pro about how to do this correctly; you might want to read it. http://tech.pro/blog/1293/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-one

Comment: @Eric Lippert thx! U make my day!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For read only collection you could use [`List<T>.AsReadOnly()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75.aspx)

```
public IList<int> MyCollection
{
   get{ return _myCollection==null  ? null : _myCollection.AsReadOnly();
}
```

If necessary and in order to make more clear that we're talking about a read only collection you could define your property like this

```
public IReadOnlyList<int> MyCollection
```

Comment: I'd probably make the return type `ReadOnlyCollection<int>` to make it plain what is happening ehre.

Comment: @Claudio Redi  - but in this case i can write something like this: SpiderMan.MyCollection.Add(123); and it will provoke an exception. so we are losing any syntax-help at this way

Comment: @secunda, changed a little bit my answer.

Comment: +1 Good answer! @secunda Isn't that what you are after? "way of protecting my List from changing" sounds to me like you want it to be ReadOnly.

Comment: @Claudio Redi -looks like perfect, but i don't see any benefits except "ReadOnly" - word.

Comment: @Jesse Webb may be i am too effeminate with C# sugar, but I was hoping to find some one-word-soolution, or something-like a syntax pattern, cause i see this task every day. So, as i can see, there is no rule and invisible problems, and each can write as he whant, but no IEnumerable<T> casting :)

Answer (score 6):

First off, if you have two questions then post two questions.  I'll answer your first question.

Second, good for you for thinking about how to protect your list from mutation. A lot of people forget about this and expose their internal state to callers.

There are a number of things you can do.

1) Don't use a mutable list in the first place. Use an immutable list. The `Add` method of an immutable list *returns a different list* rather than mutating the current list. There are new immutable list classes in the BCL now. These can be very efficient in both space and time.

2) Use a mutable list and make a copy every time.  You're already doing this. The problem is of course that it is slow and uses a lot of memory.

3) Return `AsReadOnly` as Claudio suggests.  Note that this just makes a read-only façade around the list; if the list changes, the read-only façade changes too. "Read only" means just that: the *user* cannot write it. It does not mean that it never changes. Also, there's an enumeration issue, which I'll address in (4):

4) Make LINQ do the work. `return _myCollection.Select(x=>x);` and have the property be of type `IEnumerable<int>`.  This has two downsides. First, the caller only gets forward enumeration. Second, suppose the caller is doing a `foreach` over the property, and then inside the loop does something which changes the list. This will cause an exception; you can't change a list while you're enumerating it. If you need to support that scenario then (1) or (2) are your best bet; in those the enumeration will be over a snapshot, not over the mutating list.

Comment: Eric, can you elaborate a bit on " new immutable list classes in the BCL", please ? Don't see anything like that in Collections namespace. I know there are immutable lists in F#, which we can use, but if there are immutable lists in core libraries I'd obviously prefer to use these.

Comment: return _myCollection.Select(x=>x); That is! Thx a lot. My perfectionist are dancing inside of me :)

Comment: @Eugene: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/12/18/preview-of-immutable-collections-released-on-nuget.aspx

Answer (score 2):

**Answer to the Second Question in the Question**

Iterating over an int array vs iterating over a list of integers produces very different outputs at the IL code level.

**Iterating over an Integer Array**

```
  IL_0015:  ldloc.3
  IL_0016:  ldloc.s    CS$7$0001
  IL_0018:  ldelem.i4
  IL_0019:  stloc.2
  IL_001a:  ldloc.1
  IL_001b:  ldloc.2
  IL_001c:  add
  IL_001d:  stloc.1
  IL_001e:  ldloc.s    CS$7$0001
  IL_0020:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0021:  add
  IL_0022:  stloc.s    CS$7$0001
  IL_0024:  ldloc.s    CS$7$0001
  IL_0026:  ldloc.3
  IL_0027:  ldlen
  IL_0028:  conv.i4
  IL_0029:  blt.s      IL_0015
```

**Iterating over an Integer List**

```
IL_0010:  ldloca.s   CS$5$0000
IL_0012:  call       instance !0 valuetype [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1/Enumerator<int32>::get_Current()
IL_0017:  stloc.1
IL_0018:  ldloc.0
IL_0019:  ldloc.1
IL_001a:  add
IL_001b:  stloc.0
IL_001c:  ldloca.s   CS$5$0000
IL_001e:  call       instance bool valuetype [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1/Enumerator<int32>::MoveNext()
IL_0023:  brtrue.s   IL_0010
```

The key here is that when using a list, the CLR is performing a type each iteration ( `get_Current()` object type to `int`). This may be causing performance issues.

Comment: Basically, `foreach` over an array is generated the same as the `for` loop you'd normally generate.